# Dynamically changing ListView contents

Tags: android, database, listview, android-listview

I have a `ListView` that contains entries from a `Database` of `People`. Eg...

1. Anthony Kiedis
2. John Frusciante
3. Chad Smith
4. Michael Balzary etc etc

What I am trying to implement is a `Groups` feature where you can create groups and put people into different groups and I want it to be all on one activity. So there are two buttons at the top, `All Contacts` and `Groups`. I want the `All Contacts` button to make the ListView show the people from my database and I want the `Groups` button to make the listview show all the groups that people are in. eg...

1. Friends
2. Family
3. Co-workers

(These groups will be kept in another database)

So my question is: Is this sort of functionality possible? Or am I going to have to start a new activity with it's own listView and adapter when I click on `Groups`?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to start a new activity , you just need to pass different data(List of groups) to the adapter.

Comment: Thanks alot, this worked. I never encountered any errors which is rare! haha :)

Answer (score 0):

- It's possible to show to kind of data in one ListView
- I hope u can make to fragment,when u click All Contacts u can show AllContactsFragment.
  when u click Groups u can show GroupFragment.
  if u use one ListView will make it a little complex when u click the group item to show
  the peoples in this group.
  if the UED want the group can extend and the Contact not extend.
  and if u use one ListView it wont be easy to show.
  so I suggest u should use to fragment to show two kind of the content.